# Autocomplete input field using Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery

I am working on a script that has a Bootstrap 3 popup modal which contains a form. The form has a text input field which I need to have as an autocomplete. The issue I am having is when text is entered in to the "ClientName" input field a list of possibles are not displaying.

The form code:

```
<input name="ClientName" placeholder="Client name: required field"  class="form-control" id="client_name" type="text"  required />

The autocomplete function:

$('#client_name').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url : 'check_name.php',
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        row_num : 1
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
          var code = item.split("|");
          return {
            label: code[0],
            value: code[0],
            data : item
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 1,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
    console.log("NAMES", names);
    $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
    $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/" + names[1] + "\">");
  }
});
```

The response from the "check_name.php" example:

```
["BRITA|Brita.png|LONHA","Britannia|BrittaniaPharmaceuticals.png|","Britannia Pharmaceuticals Ltd|Britannia_1.png|GILHR","British Airports Authority|baa.png|LHRPQ"]
```

The "success: function( data )" is returning the correct data so I know that part is working.

I have this working in a normal form which is not inside a Bootstrap modal but I cannot get it to work when using a modal.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try async:false option in ajax

Comment: @ Ravi thanks for your reply. I tried async:false but that had no effect.

Comment: are you getting any console error?

Comment: @Ravi No console errors. It's odd that this works in a script that does not use a modal but not when a modal is used.

Comment: did you call this after modal open?

Comment: @ Ravi Yes, the code is called after the modal is opened.

Comment: try to call this from console while modal is open. for debugging

Comment: @Ravi Hi, I am not sure how to call the form in the console, could you advise please.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript

Comment: @Ravi  When you say 'try to call this from console while modal is open' what exactly do you mean 'call this'. I am using the console to see what is been returned and everything is fine up to the point in the script 'select: function( event, ui ) {', after this I can't see any data in 'var names = ui.item.data.split("|");'. When I start to input data into the input field I was expecting a list which I could click on with the correct record but no list appears. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got Your Problem. Your suggestion box hides behind modal.

Create new container div for suggestion list and add options `appendTo: "#suggestion_container"` to assign new container for suggestion box

```js
$('#client_name').autocomplete({
  appendTo: "#suggestion_container",
  "position": { my : "right top", at: "right bottom" },
  source: function( request, response ) {
  var jsonK=["BRITA|Brita.png|LONHA","Britannia|BrittaniaPharmaceuticals.png|","Britannia Pharmaceuticals Ltd|Britannia_1.png|GILHR","British Airports Authority|baa.png|LHRPQ"];
  
  response( $.map( jsonK, function( item ) {
          var code = item.split("|");
          return {
            label: code[0],
            value: code[0],
            data : item
          }
        }));
  },
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 1,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
    console.log("NAMES", names);
    $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
    $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/" + names[1] + "\">");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input name="ClientName" placeholder="Client name: required field" class="form-control" id="client_name" type="text"  required />
          <div id="suggestion_container">
          </div><br/><br/>
          <input id="company_image_1">
          <div id="LookUpCompanyImage"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your a star. I have inserted the ajax call and this now works perfectly. many thanks for your time spent on this issue it is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi again, I know I have accepted your answer which works in part but I have an issue populating the '$('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);' after selection. Have I missed something?

Comment: Depends where your company image div is ! You want to see in modal then it should be in modal

Comment: @ Ravi Hi, the 'company image_1' div is in the modal but after selecting a item from the list the div is empty. This is how the code looks.  select: function( event, ui ) {
 var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
    $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
    $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/" + names[1] + "\">");
 }

Comment: @ Ravi  Hi, I have tried to get this to work without success, should I ask another question?